# Es posible hacer un enlace dentro del "form" HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

necesito hacer un botón que capture una variable y a la vez me redirija como un href a otra ventana mientras pasa la variable capturada. Adjunto código:

```
    <form method="GET">
        <button name="send" value="<?php echo $var1 ?>"></button>
    </form>

    <?php   
        $IDpartido = $_GET["send"];
    ?>
```

Al poner el href en el "form" o en el "button" me sigue redirigiendo a la página actual

Comment: ¿A qué página quieres llevar la información del campo del formulario `send`? Según el código que has compartido es el mismo script PHP. ¿Podrías explicar en qué archivo está cada código para entender mejor lo que deseas hacer?

Answer (score 1):

El formulario debe tener el atributo `action`. El código del `<form>` debería ser así:

```
<form action="./enviar.php">
  Nombre:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value=""><br>
  Apellido:<br>
  <input type="text" name="apellido" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Este código redirecciona los valores de tu formulario al fichero php que le asignes con las variables nombre y apellido. Y si después de enviar y procesar los datos en php quieres redireccionar a una página, agrega en el script php el siguiente código:

```
header("Location: enlace");
```

Comment: Imagino que en vez de `header ("enlace");` querías decir `header("Location: enlace");`.

Comment: Si, gracias por la corrección.

Comment: De nada. Aún así creo que esta respuesta no soluciona el problema del OP.